# Google CivicInfo API Zip Codes for PR

Tags: ruby, api, google-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to use the Civic Info API V2 to replace the now-defunct [Sunlight Labs Congressional Legislator](https://sunlightlabs.github.io/congress/legislators.html) API. To do this I am passing an zip code string as the address into the Google API.  However, when I try to pass the zip code for a Puerto Rico address, "00924" I'm returned a `404 - No information for this address`.  I get the same error when I add the city to the query, `San+Juan+PR+00924`. Puerto Rico has one Delegate Representative in the US House of Reps.

I'm using ruby's `google-api-client` gem to access the API in my program, but I get the same errors using the web API. Other zip codes work - just having troubles with this one.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get Delegate's name and information using this API?

EDIT: My current ruby code

```
def legislators_by_zip_code(zip)
  civic_info = Google::Apis::CivicinfoV2::CivicInfoService.new
  civic_info.key = '<My API Key>'

  return if zip == "00000"
  legislators = civic_info.representative_info_by_address(
                              address: zip, 
                              levels: 'country', 
                              roles: ['legislatorUpperBody', 'legislatorLowerBody'])
end
```

Comment: Can you add the code you have

Comment: I just added the code I'm currently using